# Website Performance Testing Tools

Tags: performance, asp.net, testing, load-testing

I have a contract before me that says our client will use "the following metrics will be used to determine performance standards" of the MVC4 based web site we want to deploy for them. I am looking for a tool that can help me test for these specific metrics, preferably the same tool that MS uses. The cited metrics are:

1. "Performance = The time that elapses between the HTTP Request and complete post of the web page": "Microsoft standard is <6.00 seconds"
2. "Availability test = # of successful tests divided by Total # of tests taken": "Microsoft standard is 99.9%"

I know this is more legalese than proper technical requirements, but I'm hoping some web pros with more exposure to this side of things than me might recognise the requirements and suggest a tool or approach for meeting them.

Comment: Tool recommendations are not permitted here. I do not know what MVC4 is so I will stay out of that. The <6.00 seconds should be easy to meet unless the page is a data intense page. The 99.9% is impossible. It is either 100% or something like 97.something or there about. The 99.9% is statistically impossible. I used to be a web host and as a consultant maintained many hundreds of web servers with an SLA. Having said that, you need to determine internal testing or external. External is prone to latency and DNS request times and so on. There are some excellent monitoring tools if you search.

Comment: Thank you @closetnoc. Where should I be asking then? I will close this asap.

Comment: Hold on. Check this page out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor I used to use several tools, HP SiteScope was one. I cannot remember what heads-up software I used (I think it was this: http://www.whatsupgold.com/products/) and the robot monitor software I used. That was 12 years ago! But try a Google search for "system monitoring software" Perhaps the hardware manufacturer has something like HP does.

Comment: I used to use GFI for e-mail anti-spam and anti-virus as a web host so I trust their products. Here is a web monitor from them: http://www.gfi.com/products-and-solutions/network-security-solutions/gfi-webmonitor That should get you started.

Comment: BTW- if they are serious about 99.9%, then you are in the %100 up-time SLA (service level agreement) arena and therefore would need redundancy, fail-over, and would have to remove all single points of failure which can be somewhat costly. "Are they willing to pay for?" that is my question. I used to negotiate the SLAs for a major global telecom not at all famous for their telephone booths so don't think it is them or you would be right.

Comment: Answers are closed, but you can use Apache JMeter to load test your site: https://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like

- [Web Page Test](http://www.webpagetest.org/),
- [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) and
- [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)

These will all show you detailed information about the general performance of your website, including time to first byte on first view & repeat view & time taken to load the complete document - this addresses the first requirement.

The second requirement is virtually just a fancy way of saying that the site needs to be up & running 99.9% of the time.

Comment: I know Pingdom but have not checked out the others. The problem lies with the 99.9% up-time requirement. This is often a legal construct that is covered under contract and therefore requires something robust and absolute that can be taken to court. External websites will fail this test for two reasons; ongoing extensive logging and proof, and the public nature of the offering can pollute/skew the results. In the cases where contract performance measurements are a requirement, internal and external measures must be made using systems that are designed specifically for this purpose.